# Installed open3d lib but the library is not loading

Tags: python, apple-m1, open3d

I am in the process of setting up my m1 pro max laptop. I have downloaded python, and I am installing all the required libs through pip. I am having problems installing open 3d lib.

When I run this:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

import platform
print(platform.platform())

import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d


print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("data/bun315.ply")
print(pcd)
print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

I get this error:

```
3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:44:01) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)]
macOS-12.5.1-arm64-arm-64bit

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdelnasser/Desktop/point clouds/bunny/hello.py", line 8, in <module>
    import open3d as o3d
  File "/Users/abdelnasser/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/open3d/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from open3d.cpu.pybind import (camera, data, geometry, io, pipelines,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/abdelnasser/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/open3d/cpu/pybind.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/abdelnasser/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/open3d/cpu/pybind.cpython-39-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)
```

I have searched up the error but nothing has worked. Not sure why its trying homebrew, I downloaded it to see try some things but ended up removing it from my laptop.
When trying to install the open 3d lib I have had no issues with intel and m2 air laptop, but for some reason its not working on this laptop.

Answer (score 3):

`brew install libomp` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem on Mac M2 Pro,
working now find with:
conda 23.5.0
python 3.8.16
open3d 0.17

installed with pip on conda env